# We have a web log, so now what?

Tags: discussion, blog

I have recently found this [English Language and usage blog](http://english.blogoverflow.com/). There is no content there.

I said in this [call to arms post](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1426/call-for-blog-participation) that I would like to participate by posting lessons or explanations for beginners learning English as an nth language.

What is the procedure of posting to the 'blog?

How many times a month would I and other writers be expected to provide content?

What are the rules about what is allowed in the 'blog?

Comment: The blog was just created today according to the date.

Comment: @kit is right—I just got the info. I presume one of the community coordinators is going to lead us through the process, but if not, I or another mod will be working on getting this up and running later today.

Comment: @waiwai933, drop into chat whenever you've got a chance and we can go over whatever you want. (:

Comment: @Kit & waiwai: Sorry if I came off a bit rambunctious! I was aware the blog had only just started, I just wanted to keep the momentum up and get people's interest. Feel free to make the post more docile.

Comment: Matt and @waiwai933, what's up with blog posts?  Still nothing published. ):

Comment: @Rebecca - Yes, I know. I'm sorry. It took longer than I thought to get something ready.

Comment: I'm just looking forward to seeing something posted! (:

Answer (score 4):

Just a few notes as we get the blog rolling:

1. Accounts have been set up for those who have expressed interest in contributing and who have been recently active on EL&U. If you are interested but have not received an email, please leave a comment on this post and I will follow up with you. If something is not right with your account, also leave a comment on this post or email me. Contribution is completely voluntary and at your own pace.
2. You are probably a *Contributor*. Basically, this means that you can't publish your post. The purpose of this is that so posts can be checked by an editor before being published. Naturally, this should not be much of a problem at the *English* Stack Exchange, but we'll keep this just in case. More details at [MSO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/101978/whats-the-difference-between-an-editor-author-and-contributor-on-blog-overflow/101981#101981).
3. If you are interested in becoming an *Editor*, please let me know in a comment on this post. I will get in touch with you in a few days about this.
4. A [chatroom](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1063/elu-blog) has been set up for specifically blog discussion. I will try to schedule some times that are convenient for discussion, but feel free to drop in at any time.
5. A Google Doc has also been set up for blog contributors. Because participation in this document requires you to share your email with your fellow contributors, you have not been added to this Doc. You will need to explicitly OK this in a comment here for me to add you to the list. If you are not comfortable sharing your email, then you can simply work in the chatroom and we will keep you in the loop.
6. Let's get started! Simply start writing a post whenever you're ready, and we'll work out a schedule for publishing them in the next few days.

Comment: I'd like to volunteer to be one of the editors, if possible.